# System brokes when start single test in InteliJ

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, spock

I have complex web application using Spring,Hibernate, Maven joint build(Java+Groovy) with test in Spock and different Maven profiles. All source files are in Java. I have Maven configuration(part of it) for local testing:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <path>/services</path>
           <port>8062</port>
           <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
           <backgroundProcessorDelay>2</backgroundProcessorDelay>
           <contextFile>../context.xml</contextFile>
        </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

So when I have changes in the bytecode maven **contextReloadable** triggers redeploy of the app. That is the desire state. When I run some test with maven configuration usingin InteliJ, in my system I see that redeploy is triggered.

[image]

I have no changes in the files or in the tests. But redeploy is triggered and everything is OK. But there is a problem for the same test when I click right button and click run on **UploadTest** using InteliJ 14.0.3 Community Edition

[image]

Redeploy happens but the profiles are not taken under consideration and the environment variables are not set. If I add them

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase backgroundProcess WARNING: Exception processing loader WebappLoader[/services] background process java.util.ConcurrentModificationExceptio
```

And my backendSystem crashes. So my questions are:

- Why InteliJ triggers redeploy when run Spock test without changes in the code/tests?
- Why starting a single Spock test using InteliJ, cause my backednSystem brokes(I need to restart it)(what can be the source of the problems?? InteliJ runs the test with diferent parameters, profiles are not taken or ...).
- Does inteliJ start compilation of the test with different eviroment variables set? (I see that inteliJ start its own launcher for the test).